# jQuery multiple select change event can't get option values in order of selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stock multiples choices in a input hidden when I change my select (example I select the last option then the first option) I get in my input the same order .

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var str = "";
  // For multiple choice
  $("select option:selected").each(function() {
    str = $(this).val() + str + " ";
  });
  alert(str);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="brands[]" class="chosen selectbrands fixed-width-xl" id="brands[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">BASTIEN test0</option>
  <option value="2">BASTIEN test1</option>
  <option value="3">BASTIEN test2</option>
</select>
```

Now If I change for example

> (BASTIEN test1/BASTIEN test2/BASTIEN test0)

when I run my code I get

> (BASTIEN test0/BASTIEN test1/BASTIEN test2)

this my code work fine but when I select the last then the second the problem here Is when I select the third one they don't work and I don't get the value of my option inside my var

Comment: Note that you are getting all of the selected options for all `select` elements on the page with that `"select option:selected"` selector. You likely want `$(this).find("option:selected")`. It would be better if you provided the HTML on which this code runs so that people can reproduce the issue. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to produce a runnable snippet, as in the answer.

Comment: It will be better if you add your html code and the desired output to make your question more clear

Comment: A standard `select multiple` doesn't record the *order* that you select options (as I understand the rather confusing wording in the question).   It shouldn't matter for a multi-select.  If it does matter, then you should use a different UI component, such as a list picker (two lists side-by-side where you can reorder the second list) - otherwise you're screwing with your users UX / expected operation.

Comment: I add a example in my code you can check it please !

Comment: Yes, that's how `select multiple` works - if you want something different, then use a different component.  There *may* be a 3rd party wrapper that does what you want, but it's unlikely as it's not the UX for that component.

Comment: the problem is I work with prestashop and this plugin used already by prestashop I can't  change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this may help:

Target options directly with click event and save them in order in array.
With `e.target.selected ?` you make sure push is made on selected only.
`remove` function will remove element from array if deselected.

```js
var str = []
$('select#brands option').on("click", function(e) {
  let l = $(e.target).parent().find("option:selected").length
  console.clear()

  if (l > 1) {
    e.target.selected ? str.push(e.target.value) : remove(str, e.target.value);
  } else if (l === 1 && str.length != 2) {
    str = [e.target.value]
  } else if (l === 1 && str.length === 2) {
    remove(str, e.target.value)
  } else if (l === 0) {
    str = []
  }

  console.log(str)
});


function remove(str, item) {
  var index = str.indexOf(item);
  if (index !== -1) {
    str.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="brands[]" class="chosen selectbrands fixed-width-xl" id="brands" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">BASTIEN test1</option>
  <option value="2">BASTIEN test2</option>
  <option value="3">BASTIEN test3</option>
  <option value="4">BASTIEN test4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes,This what I want exactly but the problem on click don"t work in my code !! why?

Comment: I couldn't tell you that, as seen in code snippet above it works.  Check if the selectors are alright. Target it directly with `select#brands option` btw you had `id="brands[]"` in your id, remote  `[]` . @Ahmedguesmi

Comment: @Ahmedguesmi Also use your console.log in dev tools to check for errors always or result.

Comment: I do but I can't get it the same problem

Comment: @Ahmedguesmi Sorry cant help you, code works as seen above, you have problems somewhere else maybe with implementation, I can not know without seeing it.

Comment: I found the problem , my select is multiselect that's why they add a div after my select and add a display none to select  with this way they don't found my select

Comment: can you help me!?

Comment: @Ahmedguesmi I don't know how to, your explanation of problem is confusing. In snippet above there is `select` that IS multi select : `multiple="multiple"` I don't know anything about `div's` and `display none` you are mentioning. You do not have that in your code nor I know how you page is working. And im asking myself how did your code from question even worked then?

Comment: you have a problem in your code you can't deselect you don't use cltrl+click check it

Comment: @Ahmedguesmi It works in all browsers on Mac and Windows. Just checked it as I did before posting. There is even function for remove of items on deselecting. But other thing is not working that I just noticed and that is when you select one item and then another without ctrl it counts both, I will fix that now.

Comment: @Ahmedguesmi Fixed. Now it works for single and multiple selects, and de-selecting was working.

Comment: @Ahmedguesmi Also a note, don't use `console.clear()` in production, it will remove all previous notification from console prier to that this event happens. Use it only for testing peruses of this function alone.

Answer (score 0):

Like this. When you select from the beginning, the options array is reset.

```js
    var str = "";
    $('select').change(function() {
    //alert($(this).find("option").length);
       if($(this).find("option").length < str.split(" ").length){
        str = "";
    }
      // For multiple choice
      str = $(this).find("option:selected").val() + str + " ";
      alert(str);

    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select name="brands[]" class="chosen selectbrands fixed-width-xl" id="brands[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">BASTIEN test0</option>
      <option value="2">BASTIEN test1</option>
      <option value="3">BASTIEN test2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: oh, I have done it when you select one option. I will try to do it in your way.